# Access to localhost give http error 400 independently from the application

Tags: localhost

Everytime that I try to access localhost, for example with a local webserver (like expressjs) or a local client (like react) I get an http error 400.

The problem is with every localhost independently from the application.

The only way to access localhost is with an incognito tab.

How can I fix this error?

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you figured this out since this question is almost 6 months old, but the problem is likely in the cookies stored for localhost:3000.

I had a similar problem and used a browser extension to wipe all the cookies for localhost and everything was fine after that.

For more context: I had accidentally put a loop in some React Hooks and it was trying to auth rapidly and repeatedly from Auth0 resulting in a 400 Bad Request error that wouldn't go away. I also could access my localhost in an Incognito window, which is what led me to believe that there was something in my cookies or localstorage causing the bad request.